# Filtering with elastic-search and django

Tags: django, elasticsearch, web, django-views, elasticsearch-plugin

I've configured elastic search within my django project. The next step is to apply some filtering options of those searches. The content of each search is Cars, so I'd like to be able to filter on Model, Price, Petrol/Diesel etc.
Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks,

EDIT: I'm using Haystack.

Comment: Much more information is needed. Can you provide an example, what you've tried, and error message? https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Please provide the structure/definition of your Car model so that we could help you for what you're exactly looking into.